# How would you create a "typing" effect using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a jQuery function that spells my name out letter by letter.  My name is Jake, so I want it to start out with nothing, then it'll display a J, then Ja, then Jak, then Jake. Let's just say that I'm modifying a paragraph element with class name:

```
<p class=Name> *name gets 'typed' here* </p>
```

I've tried using the .delay() function and the setTimeout() function, but I'm new to jQuery so I'm probably using them wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    setTimeout(function(){$(".name").text('J');}, 500);
    setTimeout(function(){$(".name").text('Ja');}, 500);
    setTimeout(function(){$(".name").text('Jak');}, 500);
    setTimeout(function(){$(".name").text('Jake');}, 500);

});
```

Here is a jfiddle of my most recent attempt:

http://jsfiddle.net/pg7Cu/

This just delays for 500 milliseconds then types my name all at once.  I'm trying to get it to type one letter every 500 milliseconds.  Can someone help me figure out how to do this?

Comment: Well yes, you've set the delay to 500 ms to all functions so they all happen at 500 ms.

Comment: Assuming you're not doing this as a learning execise: http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use a [recursive function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/wwbyhkx4%28v=vs.94%29.aspx):

```
var name = "Jake";

function typeName(name, iteration) {
    // Prevent our code executing if there are no letters left
    if (iteration === name.length)
        return;

    setTimeout(function() {
        // Set the name to the current text + the next character
        // whilst incrementing the iteration variable
        $('.name').text( $('.name').text() + name[iteration++] );

        // Re-trigger our function
        typeName(name, iteration);
    }, 500);
}

// Call the function to begin the typing process
typeName(name, 0);
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pg7Cu/8/).

We can extend this slightly to remove the need for initially passing in the `iteration` variable by adding this as the first line in our `typeName` function:

```
var iteration = iteration || 0;
```

Now you can simply call:

```
typeName("My name here");
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pg7Cu/10/).

Comment: any chance this can retain html tags such as <p></p>. Currently, it just displays the html tags

Answer (score 3):

Actually You can do it also with css only, No need of javascript/jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<p class="text">Jack.</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.text
{
    width: 30em;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-animation: type 5s steps(50, end);
    animation: type 5s steps(50, end);
}

@keyframes type{
    from { width: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type{
    from { width: 0; }
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/z3cUT/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple one:

http://jsfiddle.net/pg7Cu/7/

```
var text = "Hello what's up?";

function letter() {
    var oldt = $(".name").text(); // grab old text
    var t = text.charAt(0); // grab first text's letter
    text = text.substr(1); // shorten the text

    $(".name").text(oldt + t); // show old text + the one letter

    // if there's anything left to type, continue.
    if(text.length > 0) setTimeout(letter, 100);
}


$(document).ready(function()
{
    setTimeout(letter, 100);
});
```

It sets a timeout for a letter, and when the letter is shown, if there is more, it sets the timeout again. Sort of recursion.

Answer (score -2):

You're close. Start by incrementing the timeouts; as the timer starts running immediately:

```
setTimeout(function(){$(".name").text('J');}, 500);
setTimeout(function(){$(".name").text('Ja');}, 1000);
// etc
```

And don't set the differences in time exactly the same (as people don't hit a key every x ms constantly)

Check out a revised version: http://jsfiddle.net/pg7Cu/1/

And you could create more beautiful code etc. etc. but this works.

**EDIT**

Ok I took the challenge ;) Check out **[this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pg7Cu/12/)**. You can call the function `simulateTyping()` with your own string, and at random intervals it will append the next character, until the whole string is on the screen. You could even create a plugin from it (by NOT hard-coding the element the text should be appended to).

```
function simulateTyping(myString, currentChar) {
    var delay = Math.floor(Math.random()*(250-50+1)+50); // random between 50 and 250 milliseconds
    currentChar = currentChar || 0;

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.name').append(myString.charAt(currentChar))
        if(++currentChar < myString.length) {
            simulateTyping(myString, currentChar);
        }
    }, delay);
}
```

Comment: mwa, this isn't that bad, is it? could you explain the downvote? maybe I can even learn something from it ;)

Comment: Come one guys, I really don't mind getting downvoted, but I really don't see why this would be a bad answer: it is reusable and it has working demo. If you downvote, at least tell why, so myself and others who read this answer can learn why this is a bad solution.

Answer (score -3):

You can try with different timeouts:

```
setTimeout(function(){$(".name").text('J');}, 500);
setTimeout(function(){$(".name").text('Ja');}, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){$(".name").text('Jak');}, 1500);
setTimeout(function(){$(".name").text('Jake');}, 2000);
```

Comment: That's messed up. Much better would be to use "recursion" and set up new timeout after each letter is printed.

Comment: yeah, but that's just an example

Comment: haha, looking at the checkmark the OP clearly doesn't care about "messed up" or some kind of resuable code :p @user3330644 take a look at one of the other answers: they are most definitely more useful!